# Ruby on Rail: How can I use _destroy as an attribute to destroy an object on save (NOT NESTED)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have an app that uses a lot of nested objects/attributes. The general paradigm is to set `_destroy` as an attribute for something that you want to destroy. This only works for nested attributes though, and not the main object.

So this works as expected because it's nested:

```rb
params = { 
  member: {
    name: 'joe', 
    posts_attributes: [
      { title: 'A post' } 
      { title: 'A post to delete', _destroy: true } 
    ]
  }
}
```

But what I'd like to be able to do is destroy the main object in the same way:

```rb
params = { 
  member: {
    name: 'joe', 
    _destroy: true,
    posts_attributes: [
      { title: 'A post' } 
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a native way to do this or a gem? Or would I have to roll my own.

Also I recognize that since this isn't part of the framework there might be reasons this is a bad idea that I haven't considered. I'm open to hearing what those might be.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way while there is a common approach to delete objects? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/getting_started.html#deleting-articles

Comment: @Yakov yes I know about HTTP DELETE (for about 15 years now lol). But my point is there are TWO common approaches to deleting objects in Rails, and it depends on if the objects context is one of being the main object, or a nested object. In my case sometimes an object can occur in both of these contexts, and having to make my UI aware of which context is just more cruft.

Comment: @Yakov the only way to make this work currently in my UI (which has complex forms and a `save` button, is to set `_destroy` attribute on the main object anyway, and then when `save` is pressed, determine which endpoint to hit (either `update` or `delete`) based on that attribute. I'd prefer to eliminate that last step if possible.